# IconGenerator with custom view, remove padding or margin

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create this:

[image]

But unfortunately I'm only being able to get this
[image]

This question is not about the shadow or the font, I can easily adjust those I guess. What is driving me crazy is to remove the margins (or padding) between the blue line and the edges of the marker.

The relevant code is:

**On ClusterRenderer that extends DefaultClusterRenderer**

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    markerOptions.
            icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(prepareIcon(item))).
            position(new LatLng(item.getPosition().latitude, item.getPosition().longitude)).
            anchor(iconGenerator.getAnchorU(), iconGenerator.getAnchorV());

    super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
}

private Bitmap prepareIcon(MyItem item) {
    markerDecoratorView.setPrice(getPriceSpannedText(item.getPrice()));
    iconGenerator.setContentView(markerDecoratorView);
    iconGenerator.setContentPadding(-2, -2, -2, 0); // This does not make any difference
    return iconGenerator.makeIcon();
}
```

**The custom view**

```
public class MarkerDecoratorView extends LinearLayout {

@Bind(R.id.marker_item_price)
TextView markerItemPrice;

public MarkerDecoratorView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public MarkerDecoratorView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public MarkerDecoratorView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public MarkerDecoratorView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    inflate(context, R.layout.map_marker_view, this);
    this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    if (isInEditMode()) return;
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

public void setPrice(SpannableString text) {
    markerItemPrice.setText(text);
}

public void setPrice(String text) {
    markerItemPrice.setText(text);
}   }
}
```

**The view layout is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/tab_indicator" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/marker_item_price"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/MapMarker"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp"
    tools:text="SAR 300" />
</merge>
```

EDIT: I tried also with a 9patch in the custom view (xml and class). It works in Android Studio preview, but not inside the marker.

EDIT 2: I worked this out by adding a regular icon, without 9patch. I keep this question open because this topic might be relevant to others. So if anyone has the solution please post! :)

Comment: 9patch will fix it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin do you mean 9patch in the custom view or directly on the marker? Directly on the marker didn't worked out good, it generated me a rectangular marker (ie: without the arrow pointing the location). I am going to try as background of the custom view.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin thanks, but with a 9patch as a background of the view happens exactly the same. I will post update in the question.

Comment: I am not sure if that's the case for android as well, but isn't padding supposed to be only positive? Might be wrong but that's the case in CSS. That might explain why `iconGenerator.setContentPadding(-2, -2, -2, 0);` did nothing